# How to organize users in vagrant shell provision?

Tags: shell, ssh, vagrant, provisioning

So I'm setting up a vagrant environment for our small team of 4 developers. I'm using an Ubuntu/Precise32 box and I created a shell script for provisioning with lots of apt-get and cp calls. Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#filename: provision.sh
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install debconf-utils -y > /dev/null
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password myPassword"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password   myPassword"
sudo apt-get install -y vim apache2 mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client git sqlite python-pip phpmyadmin
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo pip install Django==1.4
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart


echo "Copying hosts ..."
sudo cp /vagrant/hosts /etc/

echo "Copying .gitconfig ..."
sudo cp /vagrant/.gitconfig /home/vagrant/

echo "Copying .bashrc ..."
sudo cp /vagrant/.bashrc /home/vagrant/

echo "Copying .bash_aliases ..."
sudo cp /vagrant/.bash_aliases /home/vagrant/

sudo ln -fs /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www

if [ ! -d "/vagrant/projects" ]; then
    echo "Creating folder /vagrant/projects"
    mkdir /vagrant/projects
fi

cd /vagrant/projects
#git clone myServer:/git/project.git
#can't clone because the user is vagrant. tries ssh vagrant@myServer asking for a password
```

Now I would like to clone some git repositories (from our own servers) if they don't already exist. But within the provision the active user is vagrant and I don't want to create a vagrant user on our git server or any other servers that we could use.

Each developer in the team already have their ssh accounts on other servers. So should I just create all the users in all the vagrant boxes? And if so, how can they ssh into other servers with no password?

I don't want the developers (myself included) to make user management on their own vagrant box (stuff like adduser, ssh-copy-id etc...). I want to provision everything like cloning git repositories and maybe rsync'ing but I want to be able to set up the right user for different vagrant boxes.

I want to be able to do this from shell provision:

If Vagrant box 1 => create user developer1 that already has passwordless ssh access to our servers

If Vagrant box 2 => create user developer2 that already has passwordless ssh access to our servers

If Vagrant box 3 => create user developer3 that already has passwordless ssh access to our servers

If Vagrant box 4 => create user developer4 that already has passwordless ssh access to our servers

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer, but hopefully I may be able to point you in the direction of a possible solution.

I'm guessing the /vagrant share will point to the host in your setup, in which case you could store that information in the project folder on the individual developer's machines and then call / use it in the provisioning setup.

Alternatively, try using 'Socket.gethostname' in the vagrant file - in Ruby it returns the host computer's name, so you could use this to sniff which on which developer's machine the vagrant file is running.

i.e.

```
if Socket.gethostname === 'Developer1PC'
end

if Socket.gethostname === 'Developer2PC'
end

if Socket.gethostname === 'Developer3PC'
end

if Socket.gethostname === 'Developer4PC'
end
```

You'll have to excuse any ruby errors, I'm not a ruby dev, but I've just had to do something along similar lines in Vagrant.

Comment: thanks a lot. Since I didn't get an answer very quickly, this is what I did:

I created a user called vagrant in all of our servers. This user doesn't have passoword login enabled for security. I put the ssh keys within my vagrant box, so the vagrant user can access our servers. This is not what I wanted originally but I think it makes more sense. Now every developer uses the vagrant user. When they commit the info comes from their .gitconfig file. So after setting up vagrant they have to edit their .gitconfig.example file and copy it as .gitconfig and stuff like this.